# Calling an application outside cluster from a pod

Tags: gke-networking

There is a web service app running on a Compute Engine and a GKE cluster in the same network.

Is it possible for a pod in the cluster to call the web service app using internal IP address of web service app?

Your answer will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Yes it's possible.

**Assuming that you are talking about the Internal IP address of your `VM` you will need to create a rule allowing traffic from `pod address range` to your `VM`.**

---

#### Example

Assuming that:

- There is a `Compute Engine` instance named: `nginx` and it's configured to run on port `80`.
- There is a `Kubernetes Engine` within the same network as your `GCE` instance.

You will need to check the pod ip address range of your `GKE` cluster. You can do it by either:

- `Cloud Console` (Web UI)
- `$ gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER-NAME --zone=ZONE | grep -i "clusterIpv4Cidr"`

The firewall rule could be created by either:

- `Cloud Console` (Web UI)
- `gcloud` command like below:

```sh
gcloud compute --project=PROJECT-ID firewall-rules create pod-to-vm \
--direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default \
--action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:80 --source-ranges=clusterIpv4Cidr \
--target-tags=pod-traffic
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> 1. Enter the value from last command (describe cluster) in the place of `clusterIpv4Cidr`
> 2. You will need to add `pod-traffic` to your `VM's` network tags!

After that you can spawn a pod and check if you can communicate with your `VM`:

- `$ kubectl run -it ubuntu --image=ubuntu -- /bin/bash`
- `$ apt update && apt install -y curl dnsutils`

You can communicate with your `VM` with `GKE` pods by either:

- IP address of your `VM`:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/# curl IP_ADDRESS
REDACTED
<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
REDACTED
```

- Name of your `VM` (`nginx`):

```sh
root@ubuntu:/# curl nginx
REDACTED
<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
REDACTED
```

You can also check if the name is correctly resolved by running:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/# nslookup nginx
Server:     DNS-SERVER-IP
Address:    DNS-SERVER-IP#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   nginx.c.PROJECT_ID.internal
Address: IP_ADDRESS
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Unable to connect from gke to gce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225943/unable-to-connect-from-gke-to-gce)*

Comment: Excellent! it works for me. Thanks for the detailed and thorough explanation.